# Trying to return value from column in pandas if condition in another column is not met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, apply

The piece of code I am working on looks like this.  I have a list of zip code prefixes I compare to a column of zip codes I parse down to the first three digits to obtain a true/false column if they match of not.  I have a third column that contains the state abbreviation, 'WY', 'NY', 'KY', etc, and if the zip check column is True, I want to replace whats in 'State' with 'WY', otherwise, keep what is already in that row if false.  I tried a couple of different ways and nothing wants to run.. any suggestions?

```
zips = ['820', '821', '822', '823', '824', '825', '826', '827', '828', '829', '830', '831']

df['Zip']= df['Zip'].astype(str)

df['ZipCheck']= df['Zip'].str[:3]

df['ZipCheck']= df['ZipCheck'].apply(lambda x: True if x in zips else False)
```

The code works well up to here, I get a proper True False column in Zip Check, but I cant apply it properly to the existing 'State' column below here:

```
df = df.assign(df['State']=np.where(df['ZipCheck'] == True, 'WY', df['State']))
```

Comment: This is better for `ZipCheck` definition: `df['ZipCheck'] = df['Zip'].str[:3].isin(zips)`.

Comment: Also `df.assign(State=np.where(...))` or `df['State'] = np.where(...)`.

Comment: No df['Zip Check'] works fine and populates properly with all the True/False values as compared to whats in zips, my problem is then comparing df['Zip Check'] to df['State'], df['State'] contains abbreviated state values like 'WY', 'NY', 'PA', etc, and I want to use df['Zip Check'] to say when df['Zip Check'] is True, put 'WY' in df['State'], otherwise use what is already in df['State']

Comment: 1. works fine but could be improved. 2. See my second comment for as why `df.assign` fails.

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize you were offering and improvement, I will keep that in mind for future use.  The fix to the where statement works great, I couldn't find any similar examples with searching, so thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the 'ZipCheck' column but just defining the state, you can do this :

```py
df.loc[df.Zip.str[:3].isin(zips), 'State'] = 'WY'
```

Comment: This works great, yes I did not need Zip Check so this circumvents having to delete it after performing the function and does it all in one.  Will keep this in mind for future applications!